# Como plotar um gráfico utilizando uma curve function

Tags: r, funções, plot

Preciso resolver uma questão de um curso de R. Mas não sei se fiz corretamente. Voces poderia me ajudar por favor?

A questão é a seguinte:

> Question 2. Create a vector with the cosine of numbers between -10 and 10.
>
> a) Plot the cosine of x (-10 <= x <= 10) as a function of x.
>
> b) How do you get a graph with a smooth line?
>
> c) Plot the same graph with a single command using the curve function.

Resolvi a  questão da seguinte maneira:

Q2.

b <- cos (-10:10)

- a) (essa eu não entendi muito bem o que ele pediu)

Código

```
q2 <- function (x) {
cos(x) }
Plot (q2)
```

- b) ???
- c)

Código:

```
mean(b)
sd(b) 
curve (dnorm(x, -0.08737598, 0.7360983), col = "red")
```

nesse eu não sei se posso usar `dnorm`. Mas foi a única maneira que consegui fazer o gráfico a partir de uma equação.

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de Stackoverflow não ser um lugar pra licão de casa, além de você mostrar o que você tentou a questão de plotar uma curva pode ser interessante para outras questões futuras.

A problema parece ser na sua interpretacão (Google fez uma traducão bem consistente do Inglês pra Português) de como usar a funcão `curve` ou `plot` .

- a. Trace o cosseno de x (-10 <= x <= 10) como uma função de x.

Plote `x` *vs* `cos(x)`. 
Código:

```
a<- seq(from=-10,to=10,by=0.5)
b<- cos(a)
plot(a,b)
```

Isto gera um gráfico com pontos. Neste caso usei `seq`, mas `a<- -10:10` também funciona, mas com menos pontos pois o intervalo é de 1. Se você usar uma funcão como dados para o `plot` (seja sua funcão , como você fez ou da biblioteca) ele tem o mesmo comportamento de `curve`, mas se colocar dados, ele fica como se você usar o plot.
Na sua saída, você tem apenas uma curva entre 0 e 1, no código acima, aparecem pontos entre -10 e 10.

- b. Como fazer um gráfico com uma curva suave? (Suave=Contínua)

Ele que que seja uma linha contínua, não pontos. Basta usar a tag `type='l'`. Código:

```
plot(a,b,type='l')
```

- c. Plote o mesmo gráfico num comando único, mas usando a funcão `curve`.

Como você já colocou, ele quer que seja utilizado a funcão [`curve`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.0/topics/curve) para o gerar o gráfico. Ela reproduz qualquer equacão (de x) você coloque como argumento. No seu exemplo, vocë está utilizando a funcão  [`dnorm`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.0/topics/Normal) que gera uma distribuicão normal. Basta substituir o `dnorm` por `cos` e delimitar os valores entre -10 e 10, utilizando o `from` e `to`.

```
curve(cos(x),from=-10,to=10)
```